# If I reset my iPhone 6 what iOS will be installed?

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

If I factory reset my iPhone 6 (currently running iOS 9.3.5), which version of iOS will be installed after the reset?

Comment: I imagine a lot of users might think a hard-reset would restore an earlier OS because older smartphones/smart-devices (at least the ones I used) had a built-in ROM from which the original OS was restored from during a hard-reset - any subsequent OS updates were stored in Flash (and so were lost during a hard-reset). Some early Microsoft PocketPC devices needed their ROM chips replaced for an OS update as Flash storage was so small back then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Erasing All Contents and Settings** (what most people call “factory reset”) does not change/remove your operating system. Whatever OS you had installed prior to the reset will remain after your iPhone reboots.

Comment: Your answer is related to a question I just asked: So how to can this version be determined? See  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323115/how-to-find-the-ios-version-of-a-reset-iphone