# How to find the iOS version of a reset iPhone

Tags: ios, firmware, setup

I have an old iPhone I want to sell and I don't remember which iOS version is installed on it.

I am currently presented with the "Hello" setup screen. So I can't determine which iOS version is installed.

Is there a way to find out which version is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on a background is linen texture: iOS 4, 5, 6, but it on the white background: iOS 7, 8, 9, 10, 11.
You need to activate it to see the version.